# mongoose сохраняет пустой объект

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, node.js

пишу простое приложение используя MEAN стек, когда отправляю на сервер сообщение например "hello", то в бд сохраняется пустой объект.

контроллер:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/message',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: JSON.stringify({msg: $scope.message})      
    }).

    success(function(response) {
        console.log("Success " + JSON.stringify(response));
    }).

    error(function(response) {
        console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

сервер:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));

var message = mongoose.model('Message', {
message: String
})

app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
var message = new Message(req.body);
message.save(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log(message);
})

res.status(200).send();
console.log(req.body);
})
```

вот что я получаю в консоли:

```
{msg: "hello"} // console.log(req.body);
{"_id":"584ee18f169f902b7046e991","__v":0} // console.log(message);
```

Comment: Попробуйте `var Message = mongoose.model(..)` и `var message = new Message({message:req.body});`

Comment: в скобках так и оставлять точки? поробовал, возвращает синтаксическую ошибку, ругается на точки

Comment: нет, `var Message = mongoose.model('Message', {message: String})` модель с большой буквы должна быть объявлена. Вы же потом `new Message` делаете с большой буквы, регистр имеет значение.

Comment: так тоже не работает

Comment: логов добавьте. посмотрите что приходит в `req.body`.